# Proper command order to get num_rows after fetch_array (mysqli OOP)

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm having a problem getting a `num_row` when I fetch the results as an array:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE peopleid=?";
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))) {
echo "stmt Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['peopleid'])) {
echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
   echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

$stmt->store_result();
$exist=$stmt->num_rows;
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$peopleres  = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // this does work :)
if ($exist == 0) {
//do something it it's zero
}
```

If I place the store_results and num_rows where it is in the example I get an

> Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object error.

If I place it after the fetch_array it's always equal to zero. I've used num_rows successfully before, but this is the first time I'm trying to use it alongside a fetch_array.

Comment: Ask yourself what are you doing there

Comment: Well I've read that num_rows has to come after store_result(); 343am here so what am I missing? :-)

Comment: my suggest: go sleeping and try again tomorrow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation

> **[mysqli_result::$num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)**
>   `int $mysqli_result->num_rows;`

If you want for some reason use `num_rows` instead of

```
$stmt->store_result();
$exist=$stmt->num_rows;
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$peopleres  = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // this does work :)
if ($exist == 0) {
//do something it it's zero
}
```

you may try

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$exist = $result->num_rows;
if ($exist == 0) {
    //do something it it's zero
}
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

---

Now if you're just checking whether you have any rows in the resultset or not the usage of `num_rows` is not absolutely necessary since you already get your resultset on the client. You can just try to fetch a row

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if (!$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //do something if there's no row
} else {
    //do what you have to do with you data in the row
    echo 'peopleid: ' . $row['peopleid'];
}
```

Comment: I think @YourCommonSense is right when he says that `num_rows` is unreliable and not required here - he just didn't explained it. Why not just fetching the data and count the number of records in the fetch loop? The number of records isn't required to make the script work properly. If you are interested in the count only, SQL `SELECT COUNT(..)` is more portable

Comment: @hek2mgl I totally agree with the fact that OP can manage without `num_rows` at all. As far as SQL goes most likely interested in equivalent of `EXISTS()` rather than `COUNT()` which is not the same. But then again OP asked specifically about `num_rows` and he might want to see it's working.

Comment: You should add a sentence regarding this and will earn an up-vote ;)

Answer (score -3):

num rows is a most useless function ever.
And you don't need it either. Just fetch your data and use it instead of $exists flag:

```
if(!$peopleres) ...
```

Comment: If you see reasons why `num_rows` is useless, or unreliable, you should explain them. For the very unexperienced OP this quality of answers isn't very helpful. Maybe it would being better if you  hadn't answered the question at all

Answer (score -3):

You can also use :

`$exist = $stmt->affected_rows;`

remove :

```
$stmt->store_result();
$exist=$stmt->num_rows;
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

add :
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $exist = $stmt->affected_rows;

Comment: this isn't relevant to the question