# Using mysqli_stmt::store_result causes mysqli_stmt::get_result to fail

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am trying to use BOTH mysqli_stmt::get_result and mysqli_stmt::$num_rows in the same code but they seem to be mutually exclusive. I've read the docs and the answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727608/proper-command-order-to-get-num-rows-after-fetch-array-mysqli-oop), but (contrary to the answer) it does not work. Note, the mysqlnd driver is installed.

If I add the following code, it will correctly show the number of rows

```
    $stmt->store_result();
    var_dump($stmt->num_rows)
```

BUT the following gives "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object"

```
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row  = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

However, if `$stmt->store_result();` is commented out, I get the row as desired.

How can I get `num_rows` without breaking `get_result()` ?

The reason I would like to do this is I am converting existing code to prepared statements and trying to follow the logic:

```
execute query
check number of rows
if num_rows = 0
    return
else
    fetch rows
    do something else
```

Here is a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     type varchar(20)
    );

INSERT INTO test
(type)
VALUES
('one'),
('two');
```

Code to show the problem

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "test");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "pass");

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$type = "one";
$query = "SELECT type FROM test WHERE type=?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $type);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    var_dump($stmt->num_rows);  // returns 1          

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // following gives "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object 
    $row  = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    var_dump($row);
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: How about checking out the manual http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php. Its a dirty habit, but who knows it may catch on!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have read the docs you mention and there is no mention of using `get_result()` in conjunction with `store_result()`. User comments mention the proper order of `prepare -> execute -> store_result -> bind -> fetch`. It seems that `get_result()` does the `store_result -> bind -> fetch` in one and issuing `store_result` messes it up.

Comment: Not messes it up just collects all the results for you to process using ->fetch() one row at a time.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I suppose it's perspective. In going to prepared statements, if mysqli changes the workflow (e.g. fetch all rows) or forces me to write my own functions to do what it used to do (e.g. return num_rows first), it is not an intuitive migration and so in my book, messes it up. Thanks for the response. It's clear I will have to do one or the other.

Comment: No, just read through the manual. If `store_result() is not what you want the use then dont. Use -execute(), `->bind_result()`, `->fetch` Its more like the normal mysql_ flow. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I see both points of view. I guess this boils down to client side buffering. `Does mysqli_stmt::get_result()` use client side buffering (`mysqli_stmt::store_result()` does). How important is buffering to your application, and does the difference in PHP prepared statement processing algorithms (buffered vs. unbuffered) make a difference to your application?